# Trying to save object in useState but getting undefined or Array []

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have been trying to save the result of an API call with a usestate. but I am trying to avoid an interface since the response will be very large and may vary on a case by case basis.

how would I go about saving this response?

```js
const DetailPage = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const [recipeData2, setRecipeData2] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [key, setKey] = useState('APIKEY IS HERE');

    const {id} = route.params;

    console.log(id)

    const getRecipeData2 = async() => {
        setLoading(true);


        const url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/' + id + '/information?apiKey=' + key + '&includeNutrition=false';
        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            setRecipeData2(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(recipeData2);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);

            if(error) {
                console.log('error')
            }
        });

        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getRecipeData2();
    }, [])

    return (
        <View>
          <Text></Text>  
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: First, does "console.log(response.data)" log the correct response? Second, "console.log(recipeData2)" will give you the previous value as the value of recipeData2 is only updated on the next render triggered by the setState, so you can move that log to outside your function and if the first log is logging the correct result, you should see the same value for recipeData2

Comment: Do you want to show loader and avoid user interface until response is set ?

Comment: @user3812411 console.log(response.data) gives the correct response. secondly that is where it goes wrong. Because the console.log(recipeData2) simply gives undefined. which is why i am confused about this situation

Comment: Setting the data in hooks needs some time. For that use can use `useEffect` hook with your variable dependency. useEffect will run when your state gets value.
Or you can try to console your value will a little timeout.

Comment: @DylanLucas yes, the console.log(recipeData2) will not show the new value but the previous one until the next render. Move that console log to outside the function, and you will see that it has the correct value.

Comment: You are getting `recipeData2` as undefined because you have not provided any initial value in your useState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it seems is you need to provide initial value to your `useState` and also you are not setting your loader until your promise is completed for that you can use `.finally()` block of promise.
So doing these things can fix the issue for you. Here's what needs to be done -

```js
const DetailPage = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [recipeData2, setRecipeData2] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [key, setKey] = useState('APIKEY IS HERE');

    const { id } = route.params;

    const getRecipeData2 = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/' + id + '/information?apiKey=' + key + '&includeNutrition=false';
        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            setRecipeData2(response.data);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error) console.log('error')
        }).finally(function () {
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getRecipeData2();
    }, [])

    return (
        <View>
            {
                recipeData2.map((data, index) => {
                    return <Text key={ index.toString() }> { data.title } </Text>
                })
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you. this has fixed everything. I am now trying to show a property from that object but it gives me Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never[]'. 
what am i doing wrong? this is how i called it

return (
        <View>
          <Text>{recipeData2.title}</Text>  
        </View>
    )

Comment: You are getting array but you are trying to access property so you are getting issue. I have updated the usage code.